# Not loading Bootstrap Navbar - React

Tags: reactjs, navbar, webstorm

Updated, now the problem i'm seeing the navbar with format problems, shouldn't it be taking the CSS properties from bootstrap?

I Commited the project to make it easier: https://github.com/damianaguilarcogan/pfi_front_v4

Image: https://ibb.co/fdFTb4C

---

i just created a project but the navbar it's not loading, for sure it's a silly mistake but i'm not beeing able to find it.

I created the project, imported bootstrap in the index.html trought css links.
I created the folder components and inside ir navbar.js.
Afterwards I selected a common template from bootstrap navbar and Finally y called it from my app.js.
I don't get to see whats wrong, it should have already worked with this steps.

app.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import navbar from './components/navbar';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <navbar />
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
    
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

class navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
export default navbar;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk8Lf.png
```

Comment: Hi guys, I see some advances but the Navbar it's not working as expected, I Uploaded the project to git https://github.com/damianaguilarcogan/pfi_front_v4

Comment: I see in your index.html that youre loading in Bootstrap v3.3.7, but the latest version is v4.5.2. It might be why things dont work as expected. Is there a reason why youre using an old version?

Comment: I installed lastest bootstrap version and it wasnt working so I loaded a previos versión, i will recheck using the CDN.

Comment: Instead you might want to check out https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ so you can use their components directly without the need for classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React expects components to be named with an uppercase. Try renaming the `navbar` to `Navbar`.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component

<Navbar/>
```

Comment: Hi Emre  I see some advances but the Navbar it's not working as expected, I Uploaded the project to git github.com/damianaguilarcogan/pfi_front_v4, do you know what it may be the problem? thank you again

Comment: "not working as expected" is a bit difficult to help with. Please update your question with more details as to what it is you expect, and what happens.

Comment: I will update the question because i cannot add an image in comments, the navbar it's broken, desorganized altough it seems it's triying to use bootstrap,

Answer (score 0):

Changing your navbar to Navbar works. In addition there is a bootstrap wrapper for React that can be useful if you are just starting now. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it